# Dynamically set NavigateUrl for a menu item in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I try to reach classic navigation menu item from website in c#, asp.net. My navigation menu like that  :

[image: menu]

How can I reach My Profile NavigateURL and change it? I tried this but `mi` is `null`:

```
Menu m = (Menu)Master.FindControl("NavigationMenu");
MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();
mi = m.FindItem("Account,My Profile"); 
mi.NavigateUrl = "~/MyProfile.aspx?userid=" + userid;
```

Please help :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
var menu = (Menu)Master.FindControl("NavigationMenu");
var menuItem = menu.FindItem("Account" + menu.PathSeparator + "My Profile");
menuItem.NavigateUrl = "~/MyProfile.aspx?userid=" + 123;
```

The default `PathSeparator` is a slash mark (/).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.pathseparator.aspx

If you didn't override it, then you can also use path `Account/My Profile`